# Getting stored procedure results in net core

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAllOrdersHistoryForNofshonit]
    @MemberId VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT * 
    INTO #Temptable
    FROM AttractionsOrdersHistory 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * 
    FROM MoviesOrdersHistory
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * 
    FROM SpaOrdersHistory
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * 
    FROM TzimersOrdersHistory
    WHERE MemberId = @MemberId 
END
```

I have this procedure that returns results from 4 views into a temp table.

1. How can I see the result from temp table?
2. How can I get the results into my existing code?

```
public async Task<bool> MemberOrderDateEXE(string memberId)
{
    if (memberId != null)
    {
       using (var context = ContextManager.ClubContext())
       {
          var connectionString = ContextManager.ClubContext()._connectionString;
          var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
          var command = new SqlCommand($"GetAllOrdersHistoryForNofshonit '{memberId}'", connection);

          connection.Open();

          var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
          reader.Read();

          var retValue = reader.GetValue(0);

          if(retValue != null)
          ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Should be possible. See: [How to return rowsets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/how-to-return-rowsets)

Comment: You need to add a  `SELECT (list of columns) FROM #Temptable` at the end of the procedure to actually **return** any data to the calling C# code.

Comment: if all you're doing with the temp table is populating it in one step, then selecting from it in another step... just : do a `select` that doesn't involve a temp table!

Comment: @eitan perkal And the solution?